Podman not build or run any application on Windows 11
I'm trying to build an Image using podman, I've tried a lot docs/forums and looks like nothing works.(Notice I'm new to podman)
When I run podman info command I got this:
OS: windows/amd64
provider: wsl
version: 5.1.1

Now when I try to build the dockerfile I got this error:
Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start`.
Error: unable to connect to Podman socket: failed to connect: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:53460: connectex: No connection could be made because of the target machine actively refuse it.

Then I run podman machine init and got this: Error: podman-machine-default: VM already exists
After that I run podman system connection list to review the list of machines and this is the result:
Name                         URI                                                          Identity                                                         Default     ReadWrite
podman-machine-default       ssh://user@127.0.0.1:53460/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock  C:\Users\myuser\.local\share\containers\podman\machine\machine  true        true
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@127.0.0.1:53460/run/podman/podman.sock            C:\Users\myyser\.local\share\containers\podman\machine\machine  false       true

I already remove and init the machine several times and also created a proxy to try to run this but nothing is working so far.
UPDATE
I was able to fix it applying the next steps (run commands):

podman machine reset -f this will unregister the machine
Go to the Users folder and run:
rm -r .\.config\containers
rm -r .\.local\share\containers\podman
rm -r .\AppData\Roaming\containers\

And after that I did run podman machine init the process was successful and then podman machine start with I was able to build the image I was trying to build.

Sanity check: have you run podman machine start?

Hi @cyqsimon yes I already did that and it’s not working, I got an error that says: No distribution with the given name was found
